# Meanshift in scikit learn (python) doesn't understand datatype

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a dataset which has  **7265 samples** and **132 features**.
I want to use the meanshift algorithm from scikit learn but I ran into this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\OJ\Dropbox\Dt\Code\visual\facetest\facetracker_video.py", line 130, in <module>
    labels, centers = getClusters(data,clusters)
  File "C:\Users\OJ\Dropbox\Dt\Code\visual\facetest\facetracker_video.py", line 34, in getClusters
    ms.fit(np.array(dataarray))
  File "C:\python2.7\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\mean_shift_.py", line 280, in fit
    cluster_all=self.cluster_all)
  File "C:\python2.7\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\mean_shift_.py", line 137, in mean_shift
    nbrs = NearestNeighbors(radius=bandwidth).fit(sorted_centers)
  File "C:\python2.7\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\base.py", line 642, in fit
    return self._fit(X)
  File "C:\python2.7\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\base.py", line 180, in _fit
    raise ValueError("data type not understood")
ValueError: data type not understood
```

My code:

```
dataarray = np.array(data)
bandwidth = estimate_bandwidth(dataarray, quantile=0.2, n_samples=len(dataarray))
ms = MeanShift(bandwidth=bandwidth, bin_seeding=True)
ms.fit(dataarray)
labels = ms.labels_
cluster_centers = ms.cluster_centers_
```

If I check the datatype of the data variable I see:

```
print isinstance( dataarray, np.ndarray )
>>> True
```

The bandwidth is 0.925538333061 and the `dataarray.dtype` is `float64`

I'm using scikit learn  0.14.1

I can cluster with other algorithms in sci-kit (tried kmeans and dbscan). What am I doing wrong ?

---

**EDIT:**

**The data can be found here:** 
(pickle format) : http://ojtwist.be/datatocluster.p
and : http://ojtwist.be/datatocluster.npz

Comment: What is `dataarray.dtype`?

Comment: @larsmans It is float64

Comment: I can't reproduce this with either the current scikit-learn or 0.13. Which version are you using?

Comment: 0.14, I'll see if I can upload my data.

Comment: The data can be found here in pickle format: http://ojtwist.be/datatocluster.p

Comment: Pickle is probably not the best format of data to share - in can contain arbitrary Python code, FYI.

Comment: It's so easy. If you prefer another format do tell.

Comment: Please bake an `npz` file with `numpy.savez_compressed`. I don't like pickles either.

Comment: @larsmans done, http://ojtwist.be/datatocluster.npz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That`s a bug in scikit project. It is documented [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/2356).

There is a float -> int casting during the fitting process that can crash in some cases (by making the seed points be placed at the corner of the bins instead in the center). There is some code in the link to fix the problem.

If you don't wanna get your hands into the scikit code (and maintain compatibility between your code with other machines) i suggest you normalize your data before passing it to MeanShift.

Try this:

```
>>>from sklearn import preprocessing
>>>data2 = preprocessing.scale(dataarray)
```

And then use data2 into your code.
It worked for me.

If you don't want to do either solution, it is a great opportunity to contribute to the project, making a pull request with the solution :)

Edit: You probably want to retain information to "descale" the results of meanshift. So, use a [StandardScaler](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler) object, instead using a function to scale.

Good luck!

Comment: How embarrasing, I forgot my own bug report about this :)

Comment: Lol. It was really you :P

Comment: I looked at the issue, but the solution provided there did not solve my problem. I'm now using the StandardScaler object, but that is classifying everything in one cluster which seems odd.

Comment: I'll take a look in the weekend.
Could you post a link to gist of your implementation?